# Ubuntu 20.04 don't run any applications after crash

Tags: 20.04

I have Ubuntu 20.04.
After a problem with electricity, the computer rebooted. Successfully started gdm3.
After entering the username and password, the desktop is launched.
The mouse moves. When try to running any applications, i see an attempt to run, but i didn't see window with application. the mouse keeps moving. No error messages. After trying to start something changes and now only restarting gdm3 will fix everything.

I try to reinstall ubuntu-desktop.
did not help

I try to reinstall dependencies of ubuntu-desktop.
did not help

I install XFCE and start session with it.
everything works, but i need ubuntu-desktop.

Tried running ubuntu on wayland
did not help

In which logs to see such problems?
Maybe I need reset something?
What do I need to reinstall?

Answer (score 0):

I did not wait for any advice from experts.
So I just reinstalled the system.
But that didn't help either. The strangest thing is that when the live CD was launched, everything worked fine. But after installing the new Ubuntu 20.04, the same problem returned again. I noticed that the monitor was connected to a port on the motherboard and the video was performed by the intel processor itself. I installed the video card and everything worked right away. Apparently the electrical power surge has physically damaged something. But to understand that I could not. And how to make the installed Ubuntu work like the live SD also did not figure it out. Thank you all for your attention.